# Macro exiting on range().resize().insert

Tags: excel, vba

I am relatively new to vba macros and have learned to get around, but am not very good at debugging or troubleshooting problems.

I have this macro that is exiting on the line:

.Range("B" & y_lst).Resize(34, 10).Insert Shift:=xlDown

The macro works with 2 workbooks. 'wscflow' is a sheet on the inactive open workbook 'wbsource' that are declared globally. Fluid_Results is a routine in the active workbook, but another module. 'wsactive' is the sheet the macro accesses and is set in the routine that calls Read_Complex. 'Read_Pipe' is a routine in this module.

Can anyone tell me why this line would cause the macro to exit?

I should clarify; the line executes, but exits immediately afterward, it does not execute the next line.

Regards,
arthur

```
Sub Read_Complex()
   Dim x_lst As Integer, y_lst As Integer, z_lst As  Integer, i As Integer
   wscflow.Range("T7").Value = 10
   Application.Run ("'" & wbsource.Name & "'!Set_Rng")
   x_lst = wscflow.Range("S7").Value
   z_lst = wsactive.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 23
   z_lst = ((z_lst - 24) + 330) / 34
   If wscflow.Range("O" & x_lst).Value = "Total:" Then
      x_lst = x_lst - 2
   End If
   Call Fluid_Results
   If x_lst = 10 Then
      MsgBox ("Only one pipe," & vbCr & _
           "please use Single Pipe Flow")
   Else
  For x = 10 To x_lst
     y_lst = wsactive.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 22
     wscflow.Range("T7").Value = x
     Application.Run ("'" & wbsource.Name & "'!Set_Rng")
     Application.Run ("'" & wbsource.Name & "'!Rev_Copy")
     Application.Run ("'" & wbsource.Name & "'!Fwd_Copy")
     With wsactive
        If x < 12 Then
           y_lst = y_lst - 1
           Call Read_Pipe
           If .Name = "Series_Pipe_Flow" Then
              .Range("F" & y_lst).Offset(8, 0).Formula = "=F14+F48"
              For i = 17 To 20
                 .Range("F" & y_lst).Offset(i, 0).Formula = "=F" & i + 7 & "+F" & i + 41
              Next i
              For i = 22 To 23
                 .Range("F" & y_lst).Offset(i, 0).Formula = "=F" & i + 11 & "+F" & i + 45
              Next i
           ElseIf .Name = "Parallel_Pipe_Flow" Then
              .Range("F" & y_lst).Offset(15, 0).Formula = "=F22+F56"
              .Range("F" & y_lst).Offset(19, 0).Formula = "=F27+F61"
              .Range("F" & y_lst).Offset(22, 0).Formula = "=F33+F67"
              .Range("F" & y_lst).Offset(23, 0).Formula = "=F34+F68"
           End If
        Else
           If x_lst = z_lst Then
              y_lst = y_lst - 1
           Else
              .Range("B35:K68").Copy
              .Range("B" & y_lst).Resize(34, 10).Insert Shift:=xlDown
'                  .Range("B" & y_lst).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
              y_lst = y_lst + 33
              Application.CutCopyMode = False
           End If
           Call Read_Pipe
           If .Name = "Series_Pipe_Flow" Then
              .Range("F" & y_lst).Offset(8, 0).Value = .Range("F" & y_lst).Offset(8, 0).Value _
                                                           + .Range("F" & y_lst).Offset(-20, 0).Value
              .Range("F" & y_lst).Offset(11, 0).Value = .Range("F" & y_lst).Offset(-17, 0).Value
              .Range("F" & y_lst).Offset(14, 0).Value = .Range("F" & y_lst).Offset(-14, 0).Value
              For i = 17 To 20
                 .Range("F" & y_lst).Offset(i, 0).Value = .Range("F" & y_lst).Offset(i, 0).Value _
                                                           + .Range("F" & y_lst).Offset(i - 27, 0).Value
              Next i
              For i = 22 To 23
                 .Range("F" & y_lst).Offset(i, 0).Value = .Range("F" & y_lst).Offset(i, 0).Value _
                                                           + .Range("F" & y_lst).Offset(i - 23, 0).Value
              Next i
           ElseIf .Name = "Parallel_Pipe_Flow" Then
              .Range("F" & y_lst).Offset(15, 0).Value = .Range("F" & y_lst).Offset(15, 0).Value _
                                                           + .Range("F" & y_lst).Offset(-12, 0).Value
              .Range("F" & y_lst).Offset(19, 0).Value = .Range("F" & y_lst).Offset(19, 0).Value _
                                                           + .Range("F" & y_lst).Offset(-7, 0).Value
              .Range("F" & y_lst).Offset(22, 0).Value = .Range("F" & y_lst).Offset(22, 0).Value _
                                                           + .Range("F" & y_lst).Offset(-1, 0).Value
              .Range("F" & y_lst).Offset(23, 0).Value = .Range("F" & y_lst).Offset(23, 0).Value _
                                                           + .Range("F" & y_lst).Offset(0, 0).Value
           End If
        End If
     End With
  Next x
   End If
   z_lst = wsactive.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 23
   z_lst = ((z_lst - 24) + 330) / 34
   For i = 0 To z_lst - x_lst + 1
  wsactive.Range("B" & y_lst + 1).Offset(-i * 34, 0).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
   Next i
   wscflow.Range("T7").ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value of y_lst when that line is executed?

Comment: Also, if you add "On Error Goto 0" as a line before the one in question, what happens when you run it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have a size difference between the copy and the insert. The resize function has 34 but the next one increase the variable by 33. I think the 34 needs to be 33.

If you print your variables to the debug window you'll e able to see what they are, e.g. `debug.print "y_1st = " & y_1st`.

Also for a visual add a `.Range("B" & y_lst).Resize(34, 10).Select` and break the code the next line after it to see if it has the correct size in excel.